# information theory literature beyond Cover and Thomas

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, information-theory

Can you recommend me some literature for information theory that goes beyond the book of Cover and Thomas? I know that this is a very broad question and therefore I would be happy about any suggestion that could interest me.

Preferably it should be intended to give an introduction to an active or upcoming field of information theory on the graduate level.
Texts that have a style like [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1445v5.pdf) one for quantum information theory would be great.

My intention is to find a more specific topic that interests me and then possibly get an introduction to that field.

Comment: At https://simons.berkeley.edu/workshops/schedule/854 you can find a collection of talks including some notes. Some lecture notes at http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/ITCS-spr2013/. These links are about information theory in the context of theoretical computer science.

Comment: Quite recently, I came to know the following article in arxiv about the future directions in information theory http://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05941

Answer (score 0):

**Information Theory and Statistics:**

The booklength tutorial by Shannon award winner Imre Csiszár and Paul Shields is freely available online [here](https://www.nowpublishers.com/article/Details/CIT-004):

*Information Theory and Statistics: A Tutorial*
I. Csiszár, Rényi Institute of Mathematics, Hungarian Academy of Sciences

There is also an  [article](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-642-04898-2_643) in the International Encyclopeadia of Statistical Science by E. Haroutunian which seems to be behind a paywall.

**Multiterminal Information Theory:**

Raymond W. Yeung, *Information Theory and Network Coding*, Springer, 2008.